# Read excel file in Django views using pandas module

Tags: python, django, pandas

I'm trying to read an excel file using pandas in a views method.

But the server stopped with:

```
File "/Users/ronsair/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py/_error.py", line 44, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)    
AttributeError: __name__
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

def extract(request):
  df = pd.read_excel('update.xlsx')
  return render(request, "work/index.html")
```

Can you help please?

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace? Also can you make sure the excel file is within reach of the server (check your relative path)?

Comment: print(os.path.exists('update.xlsx')) returns True

Comment: Here is the trace: https://github.com/ronscoder/Store/blob/master/error_pandas_django

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed after updating Pandas package from 0.22.0 to 0.25.3.